# Remove if and endif tags from html

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a Html string and I want to remove the if and endif tag and everything in between it.

```
<![if ..]><style>...</style><![endif]>
```

I have tried the following regex:

```
<![if.*[endif]>
<!\\[if.*\\[endif\\]>
```

Is the above regex missing some things special for box brackets?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct.

Input:

```
<![if IE]>IE<br /><![endif]>
<![if IE 6]>IE 6<br /><![endif]>
```

Pattern:

```
<!\\[if.*\\[endif\\]>
```

Matches 2 count.

But I think your actual situation is "if" and "endif" is in different line. So you have to use Singleline option to make Dot(.) include new line.

Input:

```
<![if IE]>
    IE<br />
<![endif]>
<![if IE 6]>
    IE 6<br />
<![endif]>
```

Pattern (With Singleline option):

```
<!\\[if.*\\[endif\\]>
```

Matches 1 count.

It matches, but only 1 count matching all string. Because Dot(.) searches all string ending with "[endif]>" without stopping at first "[endif]>" string.

So you have to use ? to stop at first match.

Input:

```
<![if IE]>
    IE<br />
<![endif]>
<![if IE 6]>
    IE 6<br />
<![endif]>
```

Pattern (With Singleline option):

```
<!\\[if.*?\\[endif\\]>
```

Matches 2 counts.

In addition, I think you showed wrong usage of conditional comments.

This

```
<![if ..]><style>...</style><![endif]>
```

should change to

```
<!--[if ..]><style>...</style><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html = Regex.Replace(html,@"(?is)<!\[if.*?\]>.*?<!\[endif\]>","");
```